# Not Able to Locate NgModel

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, protractor, ngmodel

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@ng-model='vm.system.systemdescription']")).SendKeys("abc"); //is able to find element. 
Whereas if do same thing using ngDriver i'm getting 

> async timeout exception or javascript Invalid operation exception 

    ngDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("vm.system.systemdescription")).SendKeys("jkgf"); 


Also tried the following but doesn't help
ngDriver.FindElement(NgByModel.Name("vm.system.systemdescription")).SendKeys("jkgf"); also does not work.                                            

Here is d code snippet                                                                              private IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        private NgWebDriver ngDriver;
        private WebDriverWait wait;
        private Actions actions;
        private int wait_seconds = 30;

        [SetUp]
        public void InitializeBrowserToSearchEngine()
        {                   ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("req_url");
             driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait_seconds));
            actions = new Actions(driver);
            Console.WriteLine("Opened Browser with the given URL");
        }
[Test]
        [Order(6)]
        public void OpenNewSystemConfig()
        {
            string url = "req_url";
            ngDriver.Url = url;
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            WebDriverWait w1 = new WebDriverWait(ngDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("Administration_1")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Administration_1")).Click();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("System_Configuration_0")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("System_Configuration_0")).Click();

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//textarea[@ng-model='vm.system.systemdescription']")));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[@ng-model='vm.system.systemdescription']")).SendKeys("ijfk");
            //w1.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(NgBy.Model("vm.system.systemdescription")));
            //ngDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("vm.system.systemdescription")).SendKeys("jkgf"); ;

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//select[@data-ng-model='vm.system.SystemTypeId']")));
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@data-ng-model='vm.system.SystemTypeId']"));
            //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(NgBy.Model("vm.system.systemdescription")));
            //ngDriver.FindElement(NgByModel.Name("vm.system.SystemTypeId"));
            // ngDriver.FindElement(NgByModel.ClassName("form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required"));
               }
```

> The commented code is not working. I need to use protractor to find the elements by ng-model and ng-binding. Since Xpath are not be used i need a way to find the element which does not have id and angular components could be find by the locators such as ng-model and ng-binding.
>   Also I have added protractor in the reference using nuget package manager
>   please help to resolve

Comment: Have you installed protractor for .net package using `Install-Package Protractor`?

Comment: Please paste the html snippet of the element if possible.

Comment: <textarea class="form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" rows="5" ng-model="vm.system.systemdescription">ijfk</textarea>

Comment: I have already installed protractor for .net package using Install-Package Protractor

Comment: <textarea class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="vm.system.systemdescription" rows="5"></textarea>

Answer (score -2):

just try `element(by.model("vm.system.systemdescription")).sendKeys('jkgf);`

You have a typo in your command sendKeys should start with small case 's' not 'S'

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks @Danny. But there are no Typos. In C#, Its Upper Case Only- As per pascal Casing coding standard.

Comment: ngDriver.FindElement(NgByModel.Name("vm.system.systemdescription")).SendKeys("jkgf"); also does not work.